# How to test Data in UI Testing in XCTest Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest

By the help of **XCTest and Accessibility** technology we are able to test UI and able to record UI Flow . So is there any procedure to test Data which are coming from the Server side in the subclass of **XCTestCase** , which help in the data validation as well as UI Validation at same time .

Comment: Are you trying to achieve data driven testing or you want to parse and validate service response?

Comment: I want to achieve data driven testing along with UI Testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test data coming from your server, this should be tested outside of a UI test. This would usually be tested completely separately from the client application.

XCTest does not allow the user to access any data directly from the target application, and only provides an interface to UI elements.